# How can I mock Firebase RemoteConfig for Test in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-remote-config

I have a function that do takes in Firebase RemoteConfig

```
func myfunction(remoteConfig: RemoteConfig) -> String {
    if (remoteConfig["my_value"].boolValue) {
        return "ABC"
    } else {
        return "DEF"
    }
}
```

I try to mock the `RemoteConfig`, but don't know how to do it.
I tried as below, and obviously, it is not working, and complaint

`Cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable: Use +remoteConfig instead.`

```
class MockRemoteConfig: RemoteConfig {
    public init() {}
}

class FirebaseServicesSpec : QuickSpec {
    override func spec() {
        describe("myfunction") {
            context("when my_value is not set") {
                it("is should return DEF") {
                    expect(FirebaseServices.myfunction(
                            remoteConfig: MockRemoteConfig())).to(equal("DEF"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I mock RemoteConfig in Swift? (In Android, I can just use `Mock()`).

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same problem and the only way I've found to do this is to generate a protocol cloning the signatures of the methods I plan to use from `RemoteConfig` in your case all that you need is a protocol that defines the subscript function

```
protocol RemoteConfigProtocol {
    func configValue(forKey key: String?) -> RemoteConfigValue // Used internally to fetch values
    subscript(_ key: String?) -> RemoteConfigValue { get } // Used to index by key like remoteConfig[key]
}

extension RemoteConfigProtocol {
    subscript(key: String?) -> RemoteConfigValue {
        return self.configValue(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

And then extend `RemoteConfig` with it

```
extension RemoteConfig: RemoteConfigProtocol {
    // Already complies since we are cloning RemoteConfig signatures
}
```

After that you should use the protocol instead of `RemoteConfig` directly

```
func myfunction(remoteConfig: RemoteConfigProtocol) -> String {
    if (remoteConfig["my_value"].boolValue) {
        return "ABC"
    } else {
        return "DEF"
    }
}
```

And for testing

```
class MockRemoteConfig: RemoteConfigProtocol {
    // We have init available!

    // Protocol stubs go here
}
```

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: How to force value for a key in MockRemoteConfig ?

Answer (score 1):

Following [Jose's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67577977/3736373). Starting with the `RemoteConfigProtocol`

```swift
protocol RemoteConfigProtocol {
    func configValue(forKey key: String?) -> RemoteConfigValue // Used internally to fetch values
    subscript(_ key: String?) -> RemoteConfigValue { get } // Used to index by key like remoteConfig[key]
}

extension RemoteConfigProtocol {
    subscript(key: String?) -> RemoteConfigValue {
        return self.configValue(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

I add the mock for `RemoteConfigValue`

```
import Firebase

class RemoteConfigValueMock: RemoteConfigValue {

    var stringMock: String?
    var boolMock: Bool = false

    override var stringValue: String? { stringMock }
    override var boolValue: Bool { boolMock }
}
```

Using it as

```
class MockRemoteConfig: RemoteConfigProtocol {
    func configValue(forKey key: String?) -> RemoteConfigValue {
      let value = RemoteConfigValueMock()
      value.stringMock = "value"
    return value
  }
}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks!